# Xcode: Child view controller doesn't load properly once given custom class name

Tags: swift, xcode, childviewcontroller

I have a view controller which has a container within it which connects to a child view controller. Everything was working great as I constructed my layout within xcode for the child view controller.

However, once I gave the child view controller a custom class name it no longer loads up properly when I start my app.

[image]

**Scenario 1:** Child view controller has no custom class name, no problem! Loads up as expected:

[image]

**Scenario 2:** I give child view controller a custom class name so I can give it functionality. Does not load up as expected!

[image]

So I can't controller my child view controller since when I attempt to connect it to a class to do so it no longer shows up. This is the first time I've used containers, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So it was a really simple resolution when I figured out what the problem was. When I created the class file I used 'Cocoa Touch Class' which includes a bunch of functions from the get go. A large number of them are commented out, except for some reason doesn't comment out overrode functions for number of sections + rows (why this is I don't know). Once I commented out these functions like the rest of them, it's loading as expected now...